# Encode a unique string every 5 second using date

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am working on a encryption project, and I basically want to get a different string every 5 seconds regardless from the platform it's being called from.

I can get a unique string every second, and this will give the same thing on any platform

```
return btoa(new Date().getSeconds().toString() + 'secret');
```

Every minute

```
return btoa(new Date().getMinutes().toString() + 'secret');
```

But, I want to do something similar to this but every 5 seconds, so that the other platform will have enough time (5 seconds) as 1 second is too short, and 1 minute is too long.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a number in milliseconds since the start of 1970. Using this would give you a unique number regardless, as long as you dont call it twice in the same millisecond.

Comment: Yes, but that would be too short, I want to use the same unique number on a different platform, and reaching that platform requires more than a second, so 5 second interval would be the sweet spot

Comment: Divide number of seconds by 5?

Comment: That would be number of seconds since the epoch actually, otherwise it would not be "unique". Note that clocks may not run synchronously, it depends if this affects your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can find using `Date`, but can easily be done by using some math.

```js
const date = new Date();
const time = date.getSeconds() - (date.getSeconds() % 5);
```

This will give you the seconds in this minute of a multiple of 5.
So every 5 seconds it goes from 0 to 5 to 10 and so on.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick, have always been a bit weak at math.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes simply dividing will give me a range of 0-4 while this will give me 0-60 and more the range the better, in my end I actually use two instances of date like the code above, but yes not the best practice I wonder if there is a better way to do that

Comment: Oh, my goodness, this is seconds in a minute, so this doesn't answer the question *you've asked*. And yeah, your calculation is terrible, division by 5 would be a range of 0..11 and 0-60 will of course never happen, and as it would skip all numbers not dividable by 5 I don't see the point either.